# Send HTML with FormData and Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, post, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to send HTML of `textarea` (TinyMCE) but the input parameter is empty.

What do I missing to make it working? Any clue?

```
$('#btnCreateContent').click(function () {

                // Checking whether FormData is available in browser
                if (window.FormData !== undefined) {

                    var fileUpload = $("#FileUpload1").get(0);
                    var files = fileUpload.files;

                    // Create FormData object
                    var fileData = new FormData();

                    // Looping over all files and add it to FormData object
                    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                        fileData.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
                    }

                    // Adding one more key to FormData object
                    fileData.append('englishTitle', $("#inputEnglishTitle").val());
                    fileData.append('englishContent', $("#editorEnglishContentCreate").val());

                    fileData.append('spanishTitle', $("#inputSpanishTitle").val());
                    fileData.append('spanishContent', $("#editorSpanishContentCreate").val());


                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("CreateContent", "Content")',
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: false, // Not to set any content header
                        processData: false, // Not to process data
                        data: fileData,
                        success: function (data) {

                        },
                        error: function (err) {
                            alert(err.statusText);
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    alert("FormData is not supported.");
                }
            });
            //
```

**C#**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult CreateContent(string englishTitle, string englishContent, string spanishTitle, string spanishContent)
{

// englishContent is empty :(
```

Comment: Use the tinyMce API to get the content or to at least update the element before you try to get it's value

Comment: What do you mean by "englishContent is empty"? Does the element `#editorEnglishContentCreate` have a value that is not an empty string when `$.ajax()` is called?

Comment: @charlietfl It seems you are right let me know how to do it please

Comment: The methods to get content or update the element are in the api docs. I don't know them off the top of my head and would have to look them up myself and no reason you can't do it. The approach does work though ... will be something like `var content = editorInstance.getContent()` or `getData()` or similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution

```
var englishContent = tinyMCE.get('editorEnglishContentCreate').getContent({ format: 'raw' });
console.log(englishContent);
fileData.append('englishContent', englishContent);
```

Also C# code needs to be adjusted like

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult CreateContent(string englishTitle, string englishContent, string spanishTitle, string spanishContent)
{
```